# CSS:Footer can't stick to bottom

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my footer stick to the bottom of the page but somehow it just can't do. I've looked in the internet for answers with no luck, so I decided to give it a shot in here.

http://jsfiddle.net/f54eq3w8/

html:

```
<div id="container">test</div>
<footer></footer>
```

css:

```
html{
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}

body{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

footer{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#003300;
    color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border-top:4px solid #B8B8B8;
}

#container{
    width:1024px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:60px;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This should help: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f54eq3w8/9/)

Use an extra div inside container to push the footer with the same height as footer's height and apply bottom margin the negative value of the footer's height to container.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="footer-push">
    </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
#container {
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    position: relative;
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto -104px auto;
}
.footer-push {
    position: relative;
    height: 104px;
}
footer {
    z-index: 99999;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #003300;
    width: 100%;
    border-top:4px solid #B8B8B8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS like this. Please note that besides the footer, I got rid of the html styling, which is the culprit of your issues

```
body{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#003300;
    color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border-top:4px solid #B8B8B8;
}

#container{
    width:1024px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:60px;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

See your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f54eq3w8/3/)